# Java DotCom game having an error message about 1/5 of the time

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am new to Java and am trying to build a DotCom game. However, about 1/5 (estimate) of the time I run this program, this error shows up:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index
>   63 out-of-bounds for length 49    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
>     at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)     at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)     at
>   AdvancedDotCom.startGame(AdvancedDotCom.java:12)  at
>   AdvDotComLauncher.main(AdvDotComLauncher.java:23)

Here's the code:
**LAUNCHER**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdvDotComLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myInt = 0;
        boolean wrong = false;
        System.out.println("Welcome! Please enter a number between 7 and 25. That will be your arena size.");
        do {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            myInt = scanner.nextInt();
            if (myInt < 7 || myInt > 25) {
                wrong = true;
                System.out.println("Please enter a number between 7 and 25.");
            }
            else {
                wrong = false;
            }
        } while(wrong == true);
        AdvDotComTable dotComTable = new AdvDotComTable();
        AdvancedDotCom dotCom = new AdvancedDotCom();
        ArrayList<String> table = dotComTable.createTable(myInt);
        dotCom.startGame(table, myInt);
    }
}
```

**TABLE CLASS**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdvDotComTable {
    public ArrayList<String> createTable(int size) {
        //Used to add the right amount elements to the Array
        int done = size * size;
        //Used for A0, A1, A2, B0, etc.
        int number = 0;
        //Used to tell when to increase the letter
        int size2 = size;
        //Used to tell which letter we're on by index
        int index = 0;
        ArrayList<String> table = new ArrayList<String>();
        char[] letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPJRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
        while (done > 0) {
            if (size2 == 0) {
                size2 = size;
                index++;
                number = 0;
            }
            table.add("" + letters[index] + number);
            number++;
            done--;
            size2--;
        }
        return table;
   }
}
```

**DOTCOM CLASS**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class AdvancedDotCom {
    public void startGame(ArrayList<String> table, int size) {
         Random random = new Random();
         char[] letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPJRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

         int chooseLetter = random.nextInt(letters[size]);
         int chooseNumber = random.nextInt(size - 3);

         char grabLetterFromTable = table.get(chooseLetter).charAt(0);
         int grabNumberFromTable = Character.getNumericValue((table.get(chooseLetter).charAt(1)));

         System.out.print("You have to guess " + grabLetterFromTable + grabNumberFromTable + ", ");
         System.out.print("" + grabLetterFromTable + (grabNumberFromTable + 1) + ", and ");
         System.out.print("" + grabLetterFromTable + (grabNumberFromTable + 2));
        }
    }
```

I have no idea what is causing this problem. I am new to Java, so it's probably a newbish mistake :P Anyways, any help I can get on this subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Debug it. The exception is clear. We aren't a free debugging service.

Comment: try to debug it, if you fail at least highlight relevant line(s) of codes where your'e facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will show your error

```
    Random random = new Random();
    char[] letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPJRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

    int chooseLetter = random.nextInt(letters[0]);

    System.out.println(chooseLetter);
```

`letters[0]` is returning the char value `A` which has a ascii value of 65, then you are calling  [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) which according to the javadocs will return a value between 0 and 65.. The weird code that you use to create your table does not create a table with this type of length

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Java. How is the code weird, and how could I improve it? Also, what would be the fix for this problem?